# Redirect user after a logout to a custom page using Spring Security?

Tags: grails, spring-security

i was wondering if there is an easy way of redirecting the user to a custom page after a succesfull logout? The logout work ok, but i want to redirect the user to a custom page. I am using Grails 1.3.7 and Spring Security Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/13%20URL%20Properties.html):

```
logout.afterLogoutUrl   URL for redirect after logout.
```